# Bugged properties window in android studio

Tags: android, linux

While this question seems stupid as hell, I can't figure out why it's happening so I gotta ask:
How do I find properties such as "onClick" and why does my properties window only feature this:

[image: ?]

[image]

Comment: I see the "linux" tag so I guess that you use Ubuntu. Could you tell me the version of your Android Studio(2.2.3 or 2.3)?

Comment: 2.3 ...........

Comment: Could you show the xml code ?

Comment: I've added a picture

Comment: Sorry, I don't figure out why... I tell you my AS2.3 behaving on win7:  
open layout(xml) and then click "Design". Now my "Properties" window is empty. Now I click a Component in "Component Tree", the relative properties come up.

Comment: I suppose this is a bug, I will reinstall AS and switch OS if the problem persists, thanks for the attempt though :)

Comment: Ok, It may be a bug...
I check my AS2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 and everything seems fine :)

Comment: Yeah its a bug, I have no problems on windows